# Parsing XML in Javascript getElementsByTagName not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to parse the following XML with javascript:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ResultSet>
    <Result>
        <URL>www.asd.com</URL>
        <Value>10500</Value>
    </Result>
</ResultSet>
```

The XML is generated by a PHP script to get how many pages are indexed in Bing.

My javascript function is as follows:

```
function bingIndexedPages() {
    ws_url = "http://archreport.epiphanydev2.co.uk/worker.php?query=bingindexed&domain="+$('#hidden_the_domain').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ws_url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xmlIn){
            alert('success');
            result = xmlIn.getElementsByTagName("Result");
            $('#tb_actualvsindexedbing_indexed').val($(result.getElementsByTagName("Value")).text());
            $('#img_actualvsindexedbing_worked').attr("src","/images/worked.jpg");          
        },
        error: function() {$('#img_actualvsindexedbing_worked').attr("src","/images/failed.jpg");}
    });
}
```

The problem I'm having is firebug is saying: **'result.getElementsByTagName is not a function'**

Can you see what is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Well have you looked at "xmlIn" with Firebug to see what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just fixed it, what I was doing wrong was when I was trying to set the value of '#tb_actualvsindexedbing_indexed' I was not telling it to use the first entry of the xml, and was just passing it the entire object.

```
$('#tb_actualvsindexedbing_indexed').val($(result[0].getElementsByTagName("Value")).text());
```

Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: $('#tb_actualvsindexedbing_indexed').val($(result[0].getElementsByTagName("Value")[0]).text()); 
??

Comment: That was what I altered to make it work. Basically just added the [0]

Answer (score 0):

result = xmlIn.getElementsByTagName("Result")[0];
            $('#tb_actualvsindexedbing_indexed').val($(result.getElementsByTagName("Value")[0]).text());

element = element; element**s** = array of elements